# Django with jQuery/datatable

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I was assigned with a task which required me to understand the following Python code which uses jQuery and datatable:

```
req = request.GET
sort_col = req['columns[%s][data]' % req['order[0][column]']]
glob_search_val = req['search[value]']
if req['order[0][dir]'] != 'asc':
```

I'm new to jQuery and datatables. The usage is quite different from how normal Python lists/dictionaries are accessed. For example, order[0][column] apparently is a variable but it's quoted which means a literal in Python. the column in the bracket appears to be a variable, it's again inside quotes and not initialized. In [datables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) order is an 2D array access by index like order[0][0]. I have similar question for data in columns[%s][data] and what does columns[%s][data] return?

Where can I find more information on how columns, order, search (and other) parameters work in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameter names you reference (sort, columns, search) are just keys in a `request.GET` [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).  There's nothing intrinsic to Django about those parameter names in a GET request (i.e. nothing magical happens in Django with those parameter key names).

The `%s` and `%s` are part of old-style [python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting), so the `%s` will be replaced by whatever is in `req['order[0][column]]` which will then store the sort column field name in `sort_col`.

As far as actual filtering/searching/ordering etc in Django, that's through the  [Django QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/). Presumably you will be sorting/ordering/searching a list of objects stored in a Database and defined in whatever Model was displayed in your Datatable e.g. `FooModel.objects.filter(some_field=search_val).order_by(sort_col)`